# How do I get rid of green numbers?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, edit-mode, faces

[image: A bunch of evil green numbers floating around selected faces in cycles edit mode]

these green numbers are there and they are bothering me and making it hard to work. I can't seem to find a reference to them anywhere. any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Whilst in `edit mode`, press <kbd>N</kbd> to open up the properties bar. Scroll down to the `mesh display` section and make sure that all `edge info` and `face info` checkboxes are unticked. [image: Checkboxes]

Hope this fixes your problem.